# Properties of the orthic triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

In the following configuration, $PQR$ is the orthic triangle of $ABC$:
[image]

I have to prove (or find) different things:

1. The sides of the orthic triangle are antiparallel to the sides of $ABC$
2. The orthocenter of $ABC$ is the incenter of $PQR$
3. Which points are $A,B,C$ with respect to $PQR$?

I would be glad to receive some hints.

Comment: how are these triangles related?

Comment: You need a figure here.

Comment: PQR(DEF) is the orthic triangle of ABC.
Added a figure to the bottom of the post.
Note:  Changed DEF to PQR to match the image.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove **1**., notice that $APQC$ is a cyclic quadrilateral and so on.
To prove **2**., perform some angle chasing.
About **3**.: if $H$ (the orthocenter of $ABC$) is the incenter of $PQR$, it follows that $A,B,C$ are the excenters of $PQR$. It is interesting to point out that **2**. implies that the orthic triangle is the cevian triangle with the shortest perimeter.

Answer (score 0):

2. Quadrilaterals APHR, PBQH, HQCR are cyclic. Triangle BQA is similar to triangle BPC.
   So angle PAH=PRH=HCQ=HRQ. Hence BR is Angle Bisector of angle PRQ and so on.Hence proved.
3. A, B, C are excentres of triangle PQR.